# Adding a row to a filtered range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a to-do list app in google sheets. I have functions for filtering by "note type" and "done status" that can be in use at any given moment by the user.

I also have functions to easily add a new note of any given type. However, when running the function to add a new note, and the sheet is already filtered, I'm getting the following error:

"This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered out row."

Any advice on how I can add a row to a filtered range?

Here is the code that I am using to add a new note of a particular type:

```
function addNewCueNote() {
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName ) {
    var noteType = "CUE"

   //ADDS ROW AND COPIES FORMULA DOWN
  //SETS VARIABLES FOR LAST ROW AND LAST COLUMN
  var lRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  //INSERT LAST ROW  
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  //COPY FORMULAS DOWN FOR SPECIFIED COLUMNS
  sheet.getRange(lRow,firstCopyCol,1,numColCopy).copyTo(sheet.getRange(lRow+1,firstCopyCol,1,numColCopy));

    //SETS NOTE TYPE    
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),noteTypeCol).setValue(noteType); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick there is something wrong with your code logic. In any ways this is a working code

```
// *** I have to add this for tests ***
var firstCopyCol = 3;
var numColCopy = 2;
var noteTypeCol = 2;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = 'MatchImport';

// ************************************

function addNewCueNote() {
  if (sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {
    var filter = sheet.getFilter();
    if (filter) {
      var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      var oldNumColumns = filter.getRange().getNumColumns();
      var newNumColumns = dataRange.getNumColumns();
      var criterias = {};
      for (var c = 1; c <= oldNumColumns && c <= newNumColumns; c++) {
        var criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(c);
        if (criteria) criterias['_' + c] = criteria;
      }
      filter.remove();
    }

    // START OF YOUR INSERT LOGIC
    var noteType = 'CUE';

    // ADDS ROW AND COPIES FORMULA DOWN
    // SETS VARIABLES FOR LAST ROW AND LAST COLUMN
    var lRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); // This is never used
    // INSERT LAST ROW
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);

    // COPY FORMULAS DOWN FOR SPECIFIED COLUMNS

    sheet
      .getRange(lRow, firstCopyCol, 1, numColCopy)
      .copyTo(sheet.getRange(lRow + 1, firstCopyCol, 1, numColCopy));

    // SETS NOTE TYPE
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), noteTypeCol).setValue(noteType);

    //* * END OF YOUR INSERT LOGIC

    if (!filter) return;
    dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var newFilter = dataRange.createFilter();
    newNumColumns = dataRange.getNumColumns();
    for (c = 1; c <= oldNumColumns && c <= newNumColumns; c++) {
      if (criterias['_' + c])
        newFilter.setColumnFilterCriteria(c, criterias['_' + c]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Grab the existing filter, remove it from the sheet, add the new row, then recreate the filter using the criteria from the initial filter.

```
function addNewCueNote() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // added to get code to run; not sure if you handle elsewhere

  if (sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {

    // Save state of existing filter before removing it
    var oldCriteria = [];
    var filter = sheet.getFilter();
    if (filter != null) {
      var oldNumColumns = filter.getRange().getNumColumns();
      for (var c = 1; c <= oldNumColumns; c++) {
        var criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(c);
        if (criteria != null) {
          oldCriteria.push([c, criteria.copy()]);
        }
      }
      filter.remove();
    }


    //*** PUT YOUR ROW INSERT LOGIC HERE ***


    // Recreate filter on new data range
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var newFilter = dataRange.createFilter();
    if (filter != null) {
      var newNumColumns = dataRange.getNumColumns();
      for (var i = 0; i < oldCriteria.length && oldCriteria[i][0] <= newNumColumns; i++) {
        newFilter.setColumnFilterCriteria(oldCriteria[i][0], oldCriteria[i][1]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kate, I'm getting an Execution failed error. Filter not found on the line where you create var oldNumColumns

Comment: @NickSolyom found the issue; updated (again) and made the solution a bit more clear.

Comment: This solution (just saving, removing, and resetting filter) is taking 9-10 seconds for me when I'm implementing it. Is that just my implementation or is that what you're getting as well?

Comment: 9-10 seconds seems long, but making several modifications to a spreadsheet *will* get expensive quickly (ex: do you have a lot of existing filters on the data?). Try checking the execution log, or add some console.time() and console.timeEnd() calls to see where the bulk of time is being spent? See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#time(String)